# Django logging: Cannot create logs per day

Tags: python, django, file, logging

I'm trying to order my logs per day, however it doesnt create a new file when it is a new day. it continues storing the logs in the previous day unless I restart the server. How could I fix that?

I'm using Django 1.4.

Thanks in advance!

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'formatters':{
    'verbose': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file_django': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/zboss/django/log_' + date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'file_modules': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/zboss/log_' + date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file_django'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'core.views': {
        'handlers': ['file_modules'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
},
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't set the date there: it'll be evaluated at import time only.

Instead, use [`logging.TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler), which adds the timestamp for you automatically, like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': os.path.join(FOOBAR, 'foobar.log'),
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: what should i provide in place of handlers['filename']?